# Avoiding extended discussion in comments section with low rep user?

Tags: discussion, comment, reputation, chat, privileges

I know it's bad practice to have extended discussions in the comments section, and I understand why. But there is no way to move the discussion to chat with a low-reputation user, and in my experience low reputation users are the most common to have extended discussions with, because they often have a lot of questions and often ask for more explanation of things.

How do I handle a situation where a low rep user has a lot of questions about an answer, but their reputation is too low to move to chat?

Comment: You can always stop responding.

Comment: These meta.SO questions seem relevant: [I'd like to propose that users with high reputation be able to chat with users with low reputation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134828/183484) and
[“Newbie” doesn't have enough reputation to talk in chat](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/99491/183484).

Comment: @Mariano Suarez-Alvarez I'm surprised that you don't have the shame to not post such a comment in a site like SE for learning.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez yes maybe that is a legitimate answer, but not the point of the site and actually really frustrating for new users, if I am correct. Also I'd assume if the OP is saying they *want* to move a discussion to the chat what you said doesn't answer their question. Unless of course, you're joking :-)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Remember that you can give *any* user an explicit write access if you are the room admin. Simply click on  “room▼” which is found under your room's name  and click on “control access”.

Now just add a user to your explicit write access. This works for any user even if they are low on reputation.

And so start inviting 'em to chat! How'd you feel if you are attended to nicely when you join the site? :-)

Comment: Comments to [this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99491/newbie-doesnt-have-enough-reputation-to-talk-in-chat/99495#99495) say that this possibility only works for mods. But it is quite an old answer, so maybe the information is out-of-date.

Comment: @Martin It works for all room owners.

Comment: This only works for mods, and that was an intentional choice by SE. I doubt they changed it. Room owners can change that list, but that is for gallery chat rooms, they still can't invite sub-20 rep users to chat.

Comment: @MadScientist But we're not specifically talking about the main Mathematics room. You might have noticed that when conversations are long-stretched in the comments, it creates a gallery chat room and does not invite you to the main chat.

Comment: those are regular chat rooms, gallery chat rooms only allow users on the write access list to talk

Comment: I accepted "move to chat" and tried clicking on “room▼” to invite the user.  It says the room is a discussion between us, but he has not responded to my "are you here?"  I don't seen any way to give access to anyone-the only options are "full transcript" and "make a bookmark".